# How Do I Replace Default Ubuntu 18.04 Wallpaper?

Tags: 18.04, desktop-background

I want to replace the default wallpaper in ubuntu 18.04. But I wonder how. I am making my own custom linux distro. can't I just replace the default wallpaper file? Or do I have to do more?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the desktop, choose "Change Background" and select a new picture in one of the ways offered.

Comment: I Mean For All Users

Comment: You didn't write "for all users" in your question, how to guess that ?